# Sporadic issues with debugging Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015 on an Android device

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

When debugging, building, and deploying in debug mode to my Nexus 9, I sometimes see sigsegv 11 and/or my breakpoints not getting hit.   I think this is due to my debug code not always getting updated on the actual device.  Why, I don't know.  I have tried all the following:

- turn OFF "use Shared Runtime"
- delete all bin and obj directories
- full clean of the entire solution

After doing a complete fetch of my entire project in a clean directory to make sure I was starting fresh, I saw that my old log statements were STILL appearing in my output.  I finally found the obsolete versions of the DLL files that should have been replaced by VS2015 on the device using ADB shell running on the Nexus:

```
flounder:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myproject.debug/files/.__override__
```

I executed in the ADB shell a rm:

```
flounder:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myproject.debug/files/.__override__ $ rm *.*
```

in the above directory on the Nexus and my debugging starting working after that.   I hope this is the end of all my issues but I'm not sure how my code ended up there anyway and why my deploy was failing to get it updated. I now make sure to change my log statements every time I deploy just to make sure that it is actually running the new code.  It's been deploying and working well since I deleted those files on the device.

So, I guess my question is, how did my debug DLL files end up in that directory (they haven't come back) and how can I avoid ending up in this situation again?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition, please change another device to check whether this issue caused by this device only. If only this device has this issue, I'm afraid this issue related to the device itself, please reboot your device and check whether there has any settings will lead to app file caches.

If other devices also has this issue, I suggest you uninstall the app from your device before you re-deploy it to device, which could make sure the old dlls are removed from your device.

Comment: Thank you.  I was hoping to avoid uninstalling since that creates a lot of work for me on the server side of my code.  I will look for more settings on the nexus to see if I can avoid this.  For now, I am just periodically removing all files from that "emulated" directory on the device so I can get a clean deploy.